# Cant insert Node to binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert Node to Binary tree. This is my function for creating Node (rest is done).

```
void BVSCreate_function(TNodef *rootPtr, function_save token) {
    TNodef *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct tnodef));
    if (newPtr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "99");
        return;
    }
    TNodef init;
    string initStr;
    initStr.str = NULL;
    initStr.length = 0;
    initStr.alloc = 0;
    newPtr = &init;
    newPtr->content = &initStr;
    newPtr->leftPtr = NULL;
    newPtr->rightPtr = NULL;
    newPtr->return_type = token.ret_value;
    newPtr->parameters = token.param_count;
    strCpyStr(newPtr->content, token.content);
    rootPtr = newPtr;
}

void BVSInsert_function(TNodef *rootPtr, function_save token) {
    if (rootPtr == NULL) {
        BVSCreate_function(rootPtr, token);
    } else {
        if ((strCmpStr(token.content, rootPtr->content)) < 0) {
            BVSCreate_function(rootPtr->leftPtr, token);
        } else
        if ((strCmpStr(token.content, rootPtr->content)) > 0) {
            BVSCreate_function(rootPtr->rightPtr, token);
        }
    }
}
```

When `TNodef` and `function_save` are structs:

```
typedef struct {
    string *content;
    int param_count;
    int ret_value;
} function_save;

typedef struct tnodef {
    string *content;
    struct tnodef *leftPtr;
    struct tnodef *rightPtr;
    int parameters;
    int return_type;
} TNodef;
```

Where `string` is defined as this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *str;  // content of string
    int length; // length of string
    int alloc;  // amount of memory allocated
} string;
```

`strCpystr` function :

```
int strCpyStr(string *s1, string *s2) {
    int len2 = s2->length;
    if (len2 > s1->alloc) {
        if (((s1->str) = (char *)realloc(s1->str, len2 + 1)) == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
        s1->alloc = len2 + 1;
    }
    strcpy(s1->str, s2->str);
    s1->length = len2 + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to create a node in binary tree and put there information from struct `function_save`.
But when I try to print this tree after insert it shows me that tree is still empty.

Comment: With `TNodef init` being declared, assigning `newPtr = &init` is a very bad idea.

Comment: An even worse idea, is to assign `newPtr = malloc(...)`, and later override it with `newPtr = &init`.

Comment: The conclusion in both cases (separately and together) is that a more basic understanding of memory allocations and value assignments is required.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb So I need to delete newPtr = &init yes?

Comment: You have a similar problem in `newPtr->content = &initStr`.

Comment: Do not use the addresses of locally-allocated variables for anything outside the scope of the function where you allocate these variables.

Comment: Can you  edit `strCpystr` function  into your post please

Comment: @ryyker I added my function

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just use the `strcpy()` function by itself?  `strCpyStr` is problematic.

Comment: where is the code for strCmpStr?

Comment: @ryyker because string is a struct so I thought it might not work with classic strcpy

Comment: okay, but you may have a memory leak there.  i.e. where are the objects allocated memory freed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `BVSCreate_function` has undefined behavior because:

- `newPtr = &init;` discards the allocated node and instead uses a local structure that will become invalid as soon as the function returns.
- `newPtr->content = &initStr;` is incorrect for the same reason: you should allocate memory for the `string` too or possibly modify the `TNodeDef` to make `content` a `string` object instead of a pointer.

Function `BVSInsert_function` does not return the updated root pointer, hence the caller's root node is never updated. You could change the API, passing the address of the pointer to be updated.

There is also a confusion in `BVSInsert_function`: it should call itself recursively when walking down the tree instead of calling `BVSCreate_function`.

Here is a modified version:

```
/* Allocate the node and return 1 if successful, -1 on failure */
int BVSCreate_function(TNodef **rootPtr, function_save token) {
    TNodef *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(*newPtr));
    string *newStr = malloc(sizeof(*content));
    if (newPtr == NULL || newStr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "99");
        free(newPtr);
        free(newStr);
        return -1;
    }
    newStr->str = NULL;
    newStr->length = 0;
    newStr->alloc = 0;
    newPtr->content = newStr;
    newPtr->leftPtr = NULL;
    newPtr->rightPtr = NULL;
    newPtr->return_type = token.ret_value;
    newPtr->parameters = token.param_count;
    strCpyStr(newPtr->content, token.content);
    *rootPtr = newPtr;
    return 1;
}

int BVSInsert_function(TNodef **rootPtr, function_save token) {
    if (*rootPtr == NULL) {
        return BVSCreate_function(rootPtr, token);
    } else {
        if (strCmpStr(token.content, rootPtr->content) < 0) {
            return BVSInsert_function(&rootPtr->leftPtr, token);
        } else
        if ((strCmpStr(token.content, rootPtr->content)) > 0) {
            return BVSInsert_function(&rootPtr->rightPtr, token);
        } else {
            /* function is already present: return 0 */
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that function `strCpyStr` may write beyond the end of the allocated area is `len2 == s1->alloc`, assuming `s1->len` is the length of the string, excluding the null terminator.

Here is a modified version:

```
int strCpyStr(string *s1, const string *s2) {
    int len2 = s2->length;
    if (len2 >= s1->alloc) {
        char *newstr = (char *)realloc(s1->str, len2 + 1);
        if (newstr == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
        s1->str = newstr;
        s1->alloc = len2 + 1;
    }
    strcpy(s1->str, s2->str);
    s1->length = len2;
    return 0;
}
```